# Spring JPA data: Querydsl in eclipse giving compilation error while using query dsl classes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have added below query dsl plugin in eclipse to generate qdsl classes.
While using DSL classes in my repository its giving complication error.

```
`
            <!--Plugin for query-dsl -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                         
                            <outputDirectory>generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory> -->
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

`
```

Also enabled annotation processing and added querydsl jar in the classpath.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With above given setting I did below changes in pom which worked perfectly.

1. Enable annotation processing in eclipse.
2. Add generated package in source in the classpath.
3. Add below changes in pom.

`

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.4</version>
            </dependency>


<!--Plugin for query-dsl -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                         
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/generated/</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

`